# Add legend to Bullet Chart in vega-lite

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite, vega

I have been trying to add a legend to the following example in Vega-lite. The visualization has a facet and each bar has independent axis. Each bar has different segments with different colors. When I tried to add a legend, it changes the color defined in each mark to the first mark and the legend overlap.

This is the example without changes:

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"title":"Revenue", "subtitle":"US$, in thousands", "ranges":[150,225,300],"measures":[220,270],"markers":[250]},
      {"title":"Profit", "subtitle":"%", "ranges":[20,25,30],"measures":[21,23],"markers":[26]},
      {"title":"Order Size", "subtitle":"US$, average", "ranges":[350,500,600],"measures":[100,320],"markers":[550]},
      {"title":"New Customers", "subtitle":"count", "ranges":[1400,2000,2500],"measures":[1000,1650],"markers":[2100]},
      {"title":"Satisfaction", "subtitle":"out of 5", "ranges":[3.5,4.25,5],"measures":[3.2,4.7],"markers":[4.4]}
    ]
  },
  "facet": {
    "row": {
      "field": "title", "type": "ordinal",
      "header": {"labelAngle": 0, "title": ""}
    }
  },
  "spacing": 10,
  "spec": {
    "encoding": {
      "x": {
        "type": "quantitative",
        "scale": {"nice": false},
        "title": null
      }
    },
    "layer": [{
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "#eee"},
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "ranges[2]"}}
    },{
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "#ddd"},
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "ranges[1]"}}
    },{
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "#ccc"},
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "ranges[0]"}}
    },{
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "lightsteelblue", "size": 10},
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "measures[1]"}}
    },{
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "steelblue", "size": 10},
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "measures[0]"}}
    },{
      "mark": {"type": "tick", "color": "black"},
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "markers[0]"}}
    }]
  },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "independent"}},
  "config": {"tick": {"thickness": 2}}
}
```

Here the changes I did without success because it change the color defined in the first 2 mark rather than having two separate scales for each mark

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"title":"Revenue", "subtitle":"US$, in thousands", "ranges":[150,225,300],"measures":[220,270],"markers":[250]},
      {"title":"Profit", "subtitle":"%", "ranges":[20,25,30],"measures":[21,23],"markers":[26]},
      {"title":"Order Size", "subtitle":"US$, average", "ranges":[350,500,600],"measures":[100,320],"markers":[550]},
      {"title":"New Customers", "subtitle":"count", "ranges":[1400,2000,2500],"measures":[1000,1650],"markers":[2100]},
      {"title":"Satisfaction", "subtitle":"out of 5", "ranges":[3.5,4.25,5],"measures":[3.2,4.7],"markers":[4.4]}
    ]
  },
  "facet": {
    "row": {
      "field": "title", "type": "ordinal",
      "header": {"labelAngle": 0, "title": ""}
    }
  },
  "spacing": 10,
  "spec": {
    "encoding": {
      "x": {
        "type": "quantitative",
        "scale": {"nice": false},
        "title": null
      }
    },
    "layer": [{
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "#eee"},
      "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "ranges[2]"},
          "color":{
            "field":"ranges[2]",
            "type":"quantitative",
            "legend":{
              "orient": "right"
            }
          }
      }
    },{
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "#ddd"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "ranges[1]"},
        "color":{
            "field":"ranges[1]",
            "type":"quantitative",
            "legend":{
              "orient": "right"
            }
        }
      }
    },{
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "#ccc"},
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "ranges[0]"}}
    },{
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "lightsteelblue", "size": 10},
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "measures[1]"}}
    },{
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "steelblue", "size": 10},
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "measures[0]"}}
    },{
      "mark": {"type": "tick", "color": "black"},
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "markers[0]"}}
    }]
  },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "independent"}},
  "config": {"tick": {"thickness": 2}}
}
```

Anyone has experience creating this type of legend
Thanks

---

I have added a color and legend to each mark to make the point that the gradient displayed is not related to the marks defined in the visualization

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "Revenue",
        "subtitle": "US$, in thousands",
        "ranges": [150, 225, 300],
        "measures": [220, 270],
        "markers": [250]
      },
      {
        "title": "Profit",
        "subtitle": "%",
        "ranges": [20, 25, 30],
        "measures": [21, 23],
        "markers": [26]
      },
      {
        "title": "Order Size",
        "subtitle": "US$, average",
        "ranges": [350, 500, 600],
        "measures": [100, 320],
        "markers": [550]
      },
      {
        "title": "New Customers",
        "subtitle": "count",
        "ranges": [1400, 2000, 2500],
        "measures": [1000, 1650],
        "markers": [2100]
      },
      {
        "title": "Satisfaction",
        "subtitle": "out of 5",
        "ranges": [3.5, 4.25, 5],
        "measures": [3.2, 4.7],
        "markers": [4.4]
      }
    ]
  },
  "facet": {
    "row": {
      "field": "title",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "header": {"labelAngle": 0, "title": ""}
    }
  },
  "spacing": 10,
  "spec": {
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"type": "quantitative", "scale": {"nice": false}, "title": null}
    },
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "red"},
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "ranges[2]"},
          "color": {
            "field": "ranges[2]",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "legend": {"orient": "right"}
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "green"},
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "ranges[1]"},
          "color": {
            "field": "ranges[1]",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "legend": {"orient": "right"}
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "yellow"},
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "ranges[0]"},
            "color": {
            "field": "ranges[0]",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "legend": {"orient": "right"}
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "blue", "size": 10},
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "measures[1]"},
          "color": {
            "field": "measures[1]",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "legend": {"orient": "right"}
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "violet", "size": 10},
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "measures[0]"},
          "color": {
            "field": "measures[0]",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "legend": {"orient": "right"}
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "tick", "fill": "black"},
        "encoding": {"x": {"field": "markers[0]"}}
      }
    ]
  },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "independent"}},
  "config": {"tick": {"thickness": 2}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the `color` given in mark to `fill` which seemed to resolve the issue.

Below is the config or refer [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoTHUFw0IAEpxSsvYpARmpzOcsBVAMpgFAAhpZP3o2BggkWWUDJQAnCLJ9IwBGMQAGBQAmDLEFAGZU1IBdJQQ4JGcYxNRDLPSMgHYikqQYgGs4GINq7KKAXwUTMwt0AAUYtgAzOkdnJld3dABSRzjZBK6aupz84pBS8oZKjYykzNzd5DaO44A2Qv7Bt2GQAHkY5Q6-LxoALwslWbzZ7eXx%20JCkOIJFbxKqGXJpBRpdI3AoXMoVWFJAp5DJNPYtdqdIxiNL3AYgIGWABycAA7n4AMJhTBsUpEgEuIaWKChWSYaFrTEAFmxuNFSLRByOyQK6SSN1JzSuRO6WL65Mp6C8ahoEAmSCgpjkM05T0soUwfkmfjEAvWRlylByQso2URkoxG0dGQULvqFwJ1yMLqF9zJIH1UDg-M0IHGtLQoCmcEEykslKUmAAnjhnmx3oEdI54EgPjFEyBBEgmCmAIJrBbpClc9AgXrtgE4A2BMhoLGduBQCtwWQ85Q9isADwr2dzlgAjgwIq4daQZlAdMNQLIaFG0PrBBA4P1m2bUPZBIIO5WkFmOkZQJdWjOc88mC1HFNL5YAMRwf9tkoI5jhOsbTrGyappYqzrDUhSASAPKCPmFaQWm6AwfocGOLOzyLsudCrv8lbkCO6GgPmNAjjGcY0GQWBtu2Dz4m0L5zug77lkoX6CL%20yj8QhwFsOOaxTqhVFQRhMIQIYSTwSeSEoRBEnoXG0myfBmavguS58oRphrko5gJJEFaUdR0F0QxTHMU%20bFvh%203E0N%206A-lA7mCaOwmgaA4FJip0HqUUjG2QS9mWJxn7Obx6DCPRmAQJg-6CEwujERAvzDFiJ5CSJvZgeJKaqfsnoaSF5J2bGuERY5EbRZYiXJalDgAplfapDlXl5WJylFZYJWHFhwVMRVYVVdp6CmFAz5OS5ICpQaz6dSBokFb1kksYSMnDe24ZHGwghrrG0Cbj1ICBB8uaRBZ148rIUz5YM00zjAu6tLI%20hdBkTFAA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "Revenue",
        "subtitle": "US$, in thousands",
        "ranges": [150, 225, 300],
        "measures": [220, 270],
        "markers": [250]
      },
      {
        "title": "Profit",
        "subtitle": "%",
        "ranges": [20, 25, 30],
        "measures": [21, 23],
        "markers": [26]
      },
      {
        "title": "Order Size",
        "subtitle": "US$, average",
        "ranges": [350, 500, 600],
        "measures": [100, 320],
        "markers": [550]
      },
      {
        "title": "New Customers",
        "subtitle": "count",
        "ranges": [1400, 2000, 2500],
        "measures": [1000, 1650],
        "markers": [2100]
      },
      {
        "title": "Satisfaction",
        "subtitle": "out of 5",
        "ranges": [3.5, 4.25, 5],
        "measures": [3.2, 4.7],
        "markers": [4.4]
      }
    ]
  },
  "facet": {
    "row": {
      "field": "title",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "header": {"labelAngle": 0, "title": ""}
    }
  },
  "spacing": 10,
  "spec": {
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"type": "quantitative", "scale": {"nice": false}, "title": null}
    },
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "#eee"},
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "ranges[2]"},
          "color": {
            "field": "ranges[2]",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "legend": {"orient": "right"}
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "#ddd"},
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "ranges[1]"},
          "color": {
            "field": "ranges[1]",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "legend": {"orient": "right"}
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "#ccc"},
        "encoding": {"x": {"field": "ranges[0]"}}
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "lightsteelblue", "size": 10},
        "encoding": {"x": {"field": "measures[1]"}}
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "steelblue", "size": 10},
        "encoding": {"x": {"field": "measures[0]"}}
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "tick", "fill": "black"},
        "encoding": {"x": {"field": "markers[0]"}}
      }
    ]
  },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "independent"}},
  "config": {"tick": {"thickness": 2}}
}
```

Comment: Thanks wahab memon. The problem is that the gradient does not have relationship with the actual color definied in the mark. I have updated the main question to reflect this issue

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a legend as I was expecting. I create another visualization mark bar and create a fake legend there, and using hcol, I concatenate this to the existing graph

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "Revenue",
        "subtitle": "US$, in thousands",
        "ranges": [150, 225, 300],
        "measures": [220, 270],
        "markers": [250]
      },
      {
        "title": "Profit",
        "subtitle": "%",
        "ranges": [20, 25, 30],
        "measures": [21, 23],
        "markers": [26]
      },
      {
        "title": "Order Size",
        "subtitle": "US$, average",
        "ranges": [350, 500, 600],
        "measures": [100, 320],
        "markers": [550]
      },
      {
        "title": "New Customers",
        "subtitle": "count",
        "ranges": [1400, 2000, 2500],
        "measures": [1000, 1650],
        "markers": [2100]
      },
      {
        "title": "Satisfaction",
        "subtitle": "out of 5",
        "ranges": [3.5, 4.25, 5],
        "measures": [3.2, 4.7],
        "markers": [4.4]
      }
    ]
  },
    "hconcat": [{
    "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "color": "green",
        "phase": 1,
        "name": "Green"
      },
      {
        "color": "silver",
        "phase": 1,
        "name": "Silver"
      },
      {
        "color": "violet",
        "phase": 1,
        "name": "Violet"
      },
      {
        "color": "yellow",
        "phase": 1,
        "name": "Yellow"
      },
      {
        "color": "red",
        "phase": 1,
        "name": "Red"
      }
    ]
  },
    "mark": "bar",
    "width": 50,
"encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "name",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {"title": null}
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "phase",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": null
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "color",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": null,
      "legend": null
    }
  }
  },{
  "facet": {
    "row": {
      "field": "title",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "header": {"labelAngle": 0, "title": ""}
    }
     
  },
  "spacing": 10,
  "spec": {
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"type": "quantitative", "scale": {"nice": false}, "title": null}
    },
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "red"},
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "ranges[2]"}
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "yellow"},
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "ranges[1]"}
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "violet"},
        "encoding": {"x": {"field": "ranges[0]"}}
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "silver", "size": 10},
        "encoding": {"x": {"field": "measures[1]"}}
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "green", "size": 10},
        "encoding": {"x": {"field": "measures[0]"}}
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "tick", "fill": "black"},
        "encoding": {"x": {"field": "markers[0]"}}
      }
    ]
  },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "independent"}}
    
  }],
  
  "config": {"tick": {"thickness": 2}}
}
```